# Align spinner to the right of edit text

Tags: android, android-edittext, spinner

I want the **spinner** to appear to the right of a **editext view**.

when i tried the below code, only the edit text appears and the spinner is totally gone. I tried many things but nothing worked.

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
tools:context=".MyActivity">

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
android:orientation="horizontal">

   <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
       <EditText
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/editText"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:hint="Duration"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
       <Spinner
       android:id="@+id/spinner"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
       android:layout_gravity="right"
       />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/startAlarm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Start Alarm Service" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopAlarm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startAlarm"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Stop Alarm" />
 </RelativeLayout>
```

how to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By setting the `width` of their container `LinearLayout` to "match_parent" & setting the `width` & `weight` of the `TextInputLayout` & the `Spinner` to **0dp** & **50** (respectively), you will get your desired layout:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:gravity="bottom"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
        android:id="@+id/text_input_layout"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="50">
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:hint="Duration"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:gravity="center"
            />
    </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        />
</LinearLayout>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/startAlarm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearlayout1"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Start Alarm Service" />
<Button
    android:id="@+id/stopAlarm"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/startAlarm"
    android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
    android:text="Stop Alarm" />
```

[image: Result]

Comment: thanks it got aligned to the right. but when i see in the app the spinner is slightly above the editText. i mean not in straight line

Comment: Delete the margins that you've set on the `TextInputLayout`. Check my edit.

Comment: Look: When you want to align 2 elements one next to another (in this case, the spinner to the right of the editText) contained in a LinearLayout, set its `layout_width` property to **match_parent**. Then all you have to do is to change the `layout_weight` property of the 2 elements that you are trying to align : in this case, I gave each of them a value of **50**, so that each of them would take half of the screen width. Imagine **100** as the total available space, it represents the value of the `weightSum` property of their container `LinearLayout`. (it's equal to **100** by default)

Comment: Nice explanation. why `gravity="bottom"` in LinearLayout?

Comment: Imagine if the `LinearLayout` (that contains the **Spinner** & the **TextInputLayout**) as if it was a box. `gravity="bottom"` tells the `LinearLayout` to put its children components **"on the ground"** (align them to the bottom).

Comment: This solution is nice, but when using `TextInputLayout` next to the `Spinner` and an underlined error displayed under the `TextInputLayout`, then the `EditText` will go up and alignment will miss ... any fix for this issue? See my screenshot please: [Alignment Issue ScreenShot](http://prntscr.com/cnnr3c)

Answer (score 0):

I'd like to be able to figure out the underlined error pushing the field up too but it seems like TextInputLayout just does this because that's the way it was designed :-(